# SPFX React useState error: Dispatch<SetStateAction<any[]>>]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I'm trying to use useState in an SPFX project. I keep getting TS error:

`error TS2488: Type '[any[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<any[]>>]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

On this line:

`const [channelsList, setChannelsList] = useState([]);`

I've updated my tsconfig to have:

`"lib": [ "es5", "dom", "dom.iterable", "es2015.collection", "es2015.promise" ]`

Which seems to have solved the linting during dev, but when saving file, or running **gulp serve** - it fails with the same error.

Question - how do I fix this?

Maybe turn off this rule in TS. Specifically in an SPFX webpart project.

Comment: The line you are referring to looks fine. Could you provide a full example? Are you trying to run this sample maybe? https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-functional-component-with-data-fetch ?

Comment: there really is nothing in the component. See this gif - https://parsonsecmpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/spfx-error.gif - as soon as I comment out the lines its fine. and as soon as i put it back - TS complains and it doesn't save

Comment: I see. Have you tried to simply create a blank new SPFx project (and just add that file)?

Comment: Yes - after a day of trying to fix this - I'm basically starting over. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real solution found for the mystery error. What I did was re-create the project with default TS config and it seems to have gone away.